# DevExpress TableView Cell does have focus on CopyingToClipboard event

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, devexpress-wpf

I am trying to fix this customized DevExpress TableView. As you guess the following method handles CopyingToClipboard. When I cast FocusedElement it is a BaseEdit but not the one that I accually have selected. Its DisplayText is different.

I have changed the background color of the cell to make sure that it has the focus and it is the one that is selected. That is not the issue. Could you please share your wisdom.

```
private void CustomizedTableView_CopyingToClipboard(object sender, CopyingToClipboardEventArgs e)
    {
        TableView view = sender as TableView;

        if (view == null || view.Grid == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        BaseEdit edit = System.Windows.Input.Keyboard.FocusedElement as BaseEdit;
        edit.Background = Brushes.Red;
        VantageUtilities.SafeCopyToClipboard(DataFormats.Text, edit.DisplayText);
        e.Handled = true;            
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DataViewBase.ActiveEditor`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataViewBase_ActiveEditortopic) property to get the focused editor or you can use [`DataControlBase.CurrentCellValue`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataControlBase_CurrentCellValuetopic) property to get the focused value.
Here is example:

```
private void CustomizedTableView_CopyingToClipboard(object sender, CopyingToClipboardEventArgs e)
{
    TableView view = sender as TableView;

    if (view == null || view.Grid == null)
        return;

    string text = null;

    if (view.ActiveEditor != null)
        text = view.ActiveEditor.DisplayText;
    else
    {
        object value = view.Grid.CurrentCellValue;

        if (value != null)
            text = value.ToString();
    }

    if (text == null)
        return;

    VantageUtilities.SafeCopyToClipboard(DataFormats.Text, text);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

PS: There are some `CopySomethingToClipboard` methods in `DataControlBase` class: [`DataControlBase.CopyCurrentItemToClipboard`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataControlBase_CopyCurrentItemToClipboardtopic) method, [`DataControlBase.CopyRangeToClipboard`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataControlBase_CopyRangeToClipboardtopic) method, [`DataControlBase.CopyRowsToClipboard`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataControlBase_CopyRowsToClipboardtopic) method, [`DataControlBase.CopySelectedItemsToClipboard`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataControlBase_CopySelectedItemsToClipboardtopic) method and [`DataControlBase.CopyToClipboard`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridDataControlBase_CopyToClipboardtopic) method. You can take a look at it.